# Any books/book you want

Tags: singular-vs-plural

What's the difference between these two sentences?

1- You can take any book you want.

2- You can take any books you want.

Answer (score 1):

In first sentence word "book" used in singular form. Which means only one book, and no more.
In second sentence book is in plural form.i.e many books, more that one

Answer (score 1):

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/any
According to this website your first example means you can take **one** of these books,
and the second one means you can take any of these books that you like and it **doesn't matter** which one you choose and you are also allowed to take **as many as** 
you want